# Angular input time mask

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have this input (Material 2) in reactive forms. And I know the better way to put a time mask (hh:mm) on this input. Or how can I build a directive for that?

```html
<div class="col-md-2 hours">
  <label for="floating-placeholder">Horário</label>
  <div>
    <input class="col-md-5 end" matInput placeholder="hh:mm" value="" name="end" minlength="4" maxlength="4" formControlName="start">
    às
    <input class="col-md-5 end" matInput placeholder="hh:mm" value=""  name="end" formControlName="end">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please enclose your inputs in a `mat-form-field`, or it's probably not going to work.

Comment: you can use https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-time-directive

Comment: @AvinashMaurya, it works only for 12 hr time, any way to make it work for 24 hr time

Comment: @SurendraMourya , At the moment it doesn't supports but we can fork and provide input for 24hrs time, let me know if you are still looking for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how i solve this question:

First i install this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask2

Then, i create a custom mask in component ts

```
public maskTime = [/[1-9]/, /\d/,':',/\d/, /\d/]
```

Finally, i put the directive in the inputs

```
  <div class="col-md-2 hours">
    <label for="floating-placeholder">Horário</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" [textMask]="{mask: maskTime, guide: false}" class="col-md-5 end" matInput placeholder="hh:mm" value="" name="end"  formControlName="start">às
      <input type="text" [textMask]="{mask: maskTime, guide: false}" class="col-md-5 end" matInput placeholder="hh:mm" value=""  name="end" formControlName="end">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `[/[0-2]/, /\d/,':',/[0-5]/, /\d/]` is more secure, but there must be also validation

Answer (score 7):

Use the standard HTML input type for time values.

```html
<input class="col-md-5 end" matInput name="end" formControlName="start" type="time">
```

For further information, see the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time).

Comment: It opens timepicker on android phone :(

Comment: For anyone looking at this, time is still not universally supported. As of today, Safari still does not support the time type.

Comment: @ThiagoNSiq Good point! However, this only applies to the Safari desktop version. All common mobile browsers (including Safari on iOS) support the time input type.

Comment: Great. Loved the behavior. Worked on my Angular 9 project via Chrome.

Comment: Very frustrating. Come on Apple, implement the time type!